# matlab finite element method (error:Not enough input arguments)

Tags: matlab, math

I have an issue in compiling my code in Matlab the error showing in the message is: Not enough input argument
I don't know how to solve it or where is the problem and I follow many documentations in the Mathworks website describes how to generalize problems 1-D with Neumann boundary conditions.
this is my code?

thank you in advance!

```
function [c,f,s] = oscpde(x,t,u,dudx)
c = 0;
f = dudx;
s = u-x*(x-1);
end
%----------------------------------------------
function u0 = oscic(x)
u0 = ((exp(1)*exp(1)+1))/(1-exp(1))*exp(0) + ((exp(1)*exp(1)+exp(1))/(1-exp(1)))*exp(0)+ 2;
end
%----------------------------------------------
function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = oscbc(xl,ul,xr,ur,t)
pl = 0;
ql = 1;
pr = 0;
qr = 1;
end
%----------------------------------------------
function [value, isterminal, direction] = pdevents(m,t,xmesh,umesh)
value = umesh;
isterminal = zeros(size(umesh));
direction = zeros(size(umesh));
end
```

**the error is:
*Not enough input arguments.
Error in CODE (line 3)
f = dudx;*
**

Comment: "compiling my code in Matlab" Matlab code isn't compiled. The error is happening on line 3 (it tells you so). `f = dudx`. How many input arguments have you give to the function `dudx`? How many does it require?

Comment: i followed this functions in that website (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/partial-differential-equations.html?fbclid=IwAR1-tYjO67bca6w8hdgSigkzw2we5zT8vUQJeNztQoeymViJPUjg-11J2fU)

Comment: The functions look fine? What does your function call line look like? Could you post that too?

Comment: how do you call the first function `oscpde(x,t,u,dudx)`. You cannot just run the file, because those are functions, which need a value for each input. So call the function from the commandline or from another file witht he inputs defined. (BTW the input `t` is not used at all in the first function)